# Can I use npm install instead of yarn add command?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

Im trying to install a package from react native firebase but the instruction stated is using yarn add specifically:

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/auth
```

However my project heavily uses npm and is it possible to use npm install instead? Like this:

```
npm install @react-native-firebase/auth
```

Do they share the same packages?

Comment: Both will work as expected, just make sure that you stick to one. Moving around from one to another will cause issues.

Comment: Yarn or NPM will work the same, they will install the same package. 

Yarn or NPM choice is just preference

Comment: ahh I see thanks! @SullivanTobias

Answer (score 1):

You can install in npm `npm install @react-native-firebase/auth --save`